# Not able to send client Request through RSC cli

Tags: spring-boot, rsocket

I am using a simple rSocket server to handle the client request. Using RSC cli to send Client request.

```
java -jar rsc.jar --debug --request --data "{\"message\":\"HiSourav\"}" --route request-response tcp://localhost:7000
```

Above is the command i am using to send the request and getting the below mentioned error.

```
Error: Could not resolve method parameter at index 0 in reactor.core.publisher.Mono<com.example.RsocketTestWithClient.entity.Message> com.example.RsocketTestWithClient.RsocketTestWithClientApplication.requestResponse(com.example.RsocketTestWithClient.entity.Message): Failed to read HTTP message; nested exception is org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Unexpected character ('m' (code 109)): was expecting double-quote to start field name; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('m' (code 109)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 1, column: 3]
```

Let me know any suggestions you have.

Comment: Can you provide debug or wiretrap results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error suggests a problem in the client,

`Unexpected character ('m' (code 109)): was expecting double-quote to start field name at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 1, column: 3]`

So I'd try to confirm you are sending the right content.

Use the --debug (or --wiretap) output to confirm that the data is correctly sent by the client. If you have done that e.g.

```
$ rsc --request --data "{\"message\":\"HiSourav\"}" --debug tcp://localhost:9000
2020-12-28 08:52:52.158 DEBUG --- [     parallel-2] i.r.FrameLogger : sending -> 
Frame => Stream ID: 1 Type: REQUEST_RESPONSE Flags: 0b100000000 Length: 31
Metadata:

Data:
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 7b 22 6d 65 73 73 61 67 65 22 3a 22 48 69 53 6f |{"message":"HiSo|
|00000010| 75 72 61 76 22 7d                               |urav"}          |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
2020-12-28 08:52:52.448 DEBUG --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] i.r.FrameLogger : receiving -> 
Frame => Stream ID: 1 Type: ERROR Flags: 0b0 Length: 102
Data:

Error: Destination '' does not support REQUEST_RESPONSE. Supported interaction(s): [REQUEST_STREAM]

Use --stacktrace option for details.
```

Then you can confirm it's a server problem and you should debug why the server is breaking here.

Comment: The error is somthing related to jsonparsing

Comment: I know, but your question isn't in a form that others can help you with.  You haven't provided test code to reproduce, or output to show what is being sent.  And you don't have a server to run.  My own testing shows that rsc sends the correct content, so it seems like a problem in your server.